# How to align the title heading in RStudio Shiny app?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am creating a basic shiny app to compile some R markdown and HTML files.

Everything works fine but I'm not really sure why the title doesn't sit on the same line as the "Introduction" and "My Notes" tabs at the top of the page.

[image: app.r pic]

Here is the basic code from app.R

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  navbarPage(titlePanel("My Jupyter Notes"),
             
             tabPanel(title = "Introduction"),
             
             tabPanel(title = "My Notes", 
                      
                      mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          type = "tabs",
                          tabPanel("Week 1"),
                          tabPanel("Week 2"),
                          tabPanel("Week 3")
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Note:** I edited out the `includeMarkdown(FILE PATH)` which would have been in the "Introduction" tab and `includeHTML(FILE PATH)` which would have been in the "Week 1/2/3" tabs under "My Notes".

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal runnable shiny app

Comment: @starja I have updated my question with the requested code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `titlePanel` is not thought to work together with `navbarPage`. In the `navbarPage`, you can use the native `title` argument:

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  navbarPage(title = "My Jupyter Notes",
             
             tabPanel(title = "Introduction"),
             
             tabPanel(title = "My Notes", 
                      
                      mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(
                          type = "tabs",
                          tabPanel("Week 1"),
                          tabPanel("Week 2"),
                          tabPanel("Week 3")
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]